# Need jQueryUI to show different images for multiple choices

Tags: jquery-ui, radio-button

I have a client that is asking for radio buttons with choices of green, yellow, red, and blue(N/A).  I have jQueryUI working fine, but obviously it only shows the base color, and a different color when clicked.

I want each radio button to load as gray by default, then change to green if you pick the first radio button, yellow if you pick the second, and so on.

To further complicate this a little bit, I'm applying it to a .NET radiobuttonlist.
Here's generated code:

```
<div id="radio" class="ui-buttonset">
   <table border="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1">
<tbody>
      <tr>
<td><input type="radio" value="2" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdoGreet1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_0" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_0" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">GREEN</span></label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="1" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdoGreet1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_1" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">YELLOW</span></label></td>
<td><input type="radio" value="0" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdoGreet1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_2" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_2" aria-pressed="true" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">RED</span></label></td><td><input type="radio" value="-1" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdoGreet1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_3" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoGreet1_3" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" aria-pressed="false" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">N/A</span></label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I'm only using the very base setup:

    $(function () {
        $("#radio").buttonset();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just overriding the appropriate css? For example, http://jsfiddle.net/william/VBGUt/.

Comment: Wow, this was embarrassingly simple.  Thanks a ton, William!